# OpenCV - How to downsample and upsample a cuFloatComplex image present in device memory

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have to downsample a image and do some filtering operations on it  and then upsample the image back to the original size, these images are present in the CUDA device memory. I planned to do it by moving the images to opencv gpumat and then using the resize function but it doesn't to be working, so I wanted to know if someone could help me with resizing the images which is of type 'cuFloatComplex'.

Pasting the snippet of my attempt below:

```
/*
Inputs
dG = image of datatype cuFloatComplex
m = rows.
n =columns.
d_input= expected output.
*/

cuda::GpuMat d_input(m,n, CV_64FC2, dG);
 cuda::GpuMat components[2];
 cuda::split(d_input,components);
 cuda::GpuMat real = components[0], imag = components[1];
```

Comment: It appears that this is an OpenCV related question, rather than a *CUDA programming* question. Which is why I have now removed the CUDA tag from this question *three* times. Please do not re-add it.

Comment: Oh thing was the data was stored in device memory and the resizing operation was to be done on CUDA, so the tag. Yeah, now that you say its a OpenCV question will just keep that tag alone. Thanks